# Should I validate my form twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

My code works perfectly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vPSm6/4/).
But the problem is that I want to add some code validation so that the form can't be submitted if something is wrong in the code. Here is the code I added:

## Jquery code:

```
 var user = document.getElementById('u');
var email = document.getElementById('em');
var pass1 = document.getElementById('p1');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pa2');
function isEmpty(input) {
  if (input.value == "" || input.value == null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function validateform() {
  if(isEmpty(user) || isEmpty(email) || isEmpty(pass1) || isEmpty(pass2))
  {
    alert("All fields are required.");
    $("#form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    if(isEmpty(user))
    {  
      user.focus();
    }
    else if(isEmpty(email))
    {  
      email.focus();
    }
    else if(isEmpty(pass1))
    {  
      pass1.focus();
    }
    else if(isEmpty(pass2))
    {  
      pass2.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

I also added an Id to my form:

```
<form action="m.php" method="post" id="form">
```

I also added the onsubmit here:

```
<input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit' onsubmit="validateform()">
```

but it is not working, the page just moves to `m.php` even if all fields are empty. what should I do? should I install the jquery validating plugin and validate twice?

**Edit**
Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vPSm6/5/)

Comment: No, you should make your validation work first time round (:

Comment: @oGeez so what's wrong with my validation here, I do not get any errors!

Comment: "but it is not working, the page just moves to m.php " - missing the 'return false" if validation fails - or the form will just carry on and submit

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `|| input.value == null` - an input element's `value` property will never be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to validate twice.

JS:

```
function isEmpty(input) {
    return $.trim(input.value) == "";
}

function validateform() {
    var user = document.getElementById('u');
    var email = document.getElementById('em');
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('pa2');

    if(isEmpty(user) || isEmpty(email) || isEmpty(pass1) || isEmpty(pass2))
        alert("All fields are required.");

    if(isEmpty(user)){
        user.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(isEmpty(email)){
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(isEmpty(pass1)){
        pass1.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(isEmpty(pass2)){
        pass2.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$('form#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( validateform() ) //just validate once!
        this.submit(); //and then submit once;
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="m.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    .....
    ......Other form settings....
    .....
    <input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: @user689: actually what you want to know? I've just updated your code! Please ask in details, so I can answer :)

Comment: Also, make sure you also validate on the server, i.e. in your PHP script. Client-side validation is nice but easy to get around!

Comment: @CompuChip should I do the same validation in m.php ?

Comment: @user689: In your code, the submit event handler will not function properly as it is not placed correctly: `$("#form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });`  The form was submitting before validation!

Comment: @user689 yes, if you want to make sure you get valid data you should. For example, I can pretty easily disable Javascript in my browser, which will allow me to submit the form without your checks ever going off. Or I could just write a manual `POST` request and send that to your server.

Also note that if the only validation you are doing is "is the field non-empty" you can use the new HTML5 `required` attribute (in addition to JavaScript/PHP checks).

Comment: @CompuChip `required` doesn't work in some browsers like safari, but I will add it.

Comment: @user689 great. It may not work everywhere, but look at it this way: `required` and JavaScript validation are just a quick first pass for user convenience. The real validation should be server side, where there is no option of circumventing it by a simple browser choice or setting.

Comment: @CompuChip thanks for your help. will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

After you check if the field is empty if you `return false;` then the from will not submit.
Form on submit [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_onsubmit).

**JavaScript**

```
function validateform() {
    if(isEmpty(user))
    {  
        user.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(isEmpty(email))
    {  
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(isEmpty(pass1))
    {  
        pass1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(isEmpty(pass2))
    {  
        pass2.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your `onsubmit` needs to be on your form not your button.
**HTML**

```
<form action="m.php" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="validateform()">
<input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit' >
```

Comment: I tried this before asking the question and now but it is still not working, should I remove the event.preventdefault();

Comment: @user689 yes make your validateform method look exactly like mine

Comment: @user689 your onsubmit needs to be on your form, see updated answer there seem so be a bug where onsubmit does not work in JSFiddle